# Listener not working after installing Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-12c, listener

I have installed Oracle 11g on a machine which was already running Oracle 12c. Now the listeners configured for 12c are not started. Lsnrctl status shows the listener parameter file of 11g. How to change it?

Comment: Start listener from 12c Oracle home `$ORA_HOME12c/bin/lsnrctl start listener`

Answer (score -1):

Start it from the 11g bin directory- lsnrctl start

Is it a windows machine? you can go into services and select which one to start on startup